# jquery time ago with unix epoch

Tags: jquery, django

I'm using django currently and outputting the date in seconds from the unix epoch.  How do I use jquery time ago with unix epoch?

I see this example:
January 10, 2015

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2015-01-10T15:00:00Z">January 10, 2015</abbr>
```

but can i do something like:

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2015-01-10T15:00:00Z">{{UNIX_EPOCH_IN_SECONDS}}</abbr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with jQuery. Are you looking for a client-side method (JavaScript), or a server-side one (Python)?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to convert your unix timestamp to ISO. Hal posted a piece of code modifying jQuery's [timeago plugin](http://timeago.yarp.com/) that worked for me. Simply replace timeago's parse() function at line 89 with this:

```
parse: function(iso8601) {  
  if ((iso8601 - 0) == iso8601 && iso8601.length > 0) { // Checks if iso8601 is a unix timestamp  
    var s = new Date(iso8601);  
    if (isNaN(s.getTime())) { // Checks if iso8601 is formatted in milliseconds  
      var s = new Date(iso8601 * 1000); //if not, add milliseconds 
    }
    return s;  
  }  

  var s = $.trim(iso8601);
  s = s.replace(/-/,"/").replace(/-/,"/");
  s = s.replace(/T/," ").replace(/Z/," UTC");
  s = s.replace(/([\+-]\d\d)\:?(\d\d)/," $1$2"); // -04:00 -> -0400
  return new Date(s);
},
```

[jQuery Time ago from a timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2102815/jquery-time-ago-from-a-timestamp/2871159#2871159)

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize a `Date` object with a unix timestamp, but Javascript's date expects time in milliseconds, so it's simply:

```
var d = new Date(<?php echo date('U') ?>000);
```

which turns into something like:

```
var d = new Date(1285027311000);
```

It'll also parse most standard textual date formats, must as PHP's strtotime() will, though you'll have to test exactly how forgiving it is.

Comment: Maybe I missed your point but the question was about jQuery and django?

Answer (score 2):

The Date() constructor can take the number of milliseconds since 00:00:00 UTC 1/1/1970, and timeago can be used with a Date object. So:

```
jQuery.timeago(new Date(unixSeconds * 1000));
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**
First add JQuery and timeago jquery plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://timeago.yarp.com/jquery.timeago.js"></script>
```

**Step 2** 
No need to write anything in between  tags

```
<abbr class="timeago" title="2015-01-10T15:00:00Z"></abbr>
```

**Step 3**
Use the following JQuery code

```
var postAddDate = new Date($(".timeago").attr("title"));
var timeAgo = jQuery.timeago(postAddDate);
$(".timeago").html(timeAgo);
```

**Memory efficient version**

```
$(".timeago").html(jQuery.timeago(new Date($(".timeago").attr("title"))));
```

[See in Codepen](https://codepen.io/yvzyildirim/pen/JaZKwj)